# Proving $n! = n \Rightarrow (n = 1 \quad or \quad n = 2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I want to know whether my proof is correct. Any elegant proofs are welcome.

> $n\in\mathbb{N}.\quad$**Prove** $ (n!=n) \Rightarrow (n=1\quad or\quad n=2)$

$ (n!=n) \Rightarrow (n=1\quad or\quad n=2) \equiv$

$(n\neq1\quad and\quad n\neq2) \Rightarrow (n!\neq n) \equiv$

$n>2 \Rightarrow (n!\neq n)$

Suppose $n>2$. Suppose $n!=n$.

Then $n!=n \equiv $

$(n-1)!=1 \equiv$

$(n-1)(n-2)!=1 \quad, (n-2)!$ is defined since $n>2$

Thus, $(n-2)! = 1/(n-1)$

but $(n-2)!\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1/(n-1)\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, so contradiction.

Therefore $ (n!=n) \Rightarrow (n=1\quad or\quad n=2)$

Comment: Your proof looks good. Just add one more sentence why $\frac{1}{n-1}$ cannot be in $\mathbb N$

Comment: $0!>0,\color{green}{1!=1},\color{green}{2!=2},3!=3.2!>3,4!=4.3!>4\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n!>n$, then
$$
(n+1)! = (n+1)n! > (n+1)n > n+1
$$
as long as $n>1$. Now, $3!>3$, and by induction we have proved that $n!>n$ for all $n \geq 3$. Since $1!=1$ and $2!=2$, the assertion is proved.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, $n\ne0$, and we can simplify:

$$(n-1)!=1.$$

By inspection, $n-1=0$ and $n-1=1$ are solutions. All other factorials have a factor that makes them exceed $1$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $n>2\implies n!>n$ you can use induction.

Base case: $3!=6>3$

Induction step: if $n!>n$ and $n>2$ then $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)>n(n+1)>n+1$.

Answer (score -1):

This seems shorter:

If $n = 1$ or $n = 2$, then  $n! / n = 1$ and thus $n! = n$.

If $n > 2$, then $n! / n = (n-1)! \geq 2$ and thus $n! \neq n$.

Therefore, $n \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{ 0 \}$, $n! = n \Rightarrow n = 1 \vee 2$.

Comment: What if $(n-1)!=2$?

Comment: "If $n>2$, then $n!/n = (n-1)! > 2$" **false**. See $n=3$ for example.

Comment: Corrected the minor mistake indicated by 5xum.